# Theorem 3, section 15 in Halmos' book

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> If $u$ and $v$ are any two different vectors of the $n$-dimentional vector space, then there exists a linear function $y$ on $V$ such that $[u,y]\neq [v,y]$. (...)

It is taken from the book, Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces by Halmos.

**My proof**: Let $x$ be a non-zero vector in $V$. Then $\{x\}$ is linearly independent. Since $V$ has $n$ dimension, it has a finite spanning set. By Theorem, section 7 in Halmos, that linearly independent set can be extended to a basis for $V$. Therefore, there exist $x_2,\dots, x_n\in V$ such that $X:=\{x,x_2,\dots, x_n\}$ forms a basis for $V$. Now let $\{y_1,\dots, y_n\}$ be the dual basis of $X$. We see that $[x,y_1]=1\neq 0$, sine $x$ is the first element of $X$, we conclude that there exists a functional $y$ such that $[x,y]\neq 0$. Thus, the claim follows by letting $x=u-v$, as $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is linear with respect to the first entry. QED.

I'd like to know what you think aboud the proof-writing. I have been usure about writing on extending the linearly independent set to a basis. I avoided to mention explicitly the vectors that spans $V$, let's say $z_1,\dots, z_m$ where $n\leq m$, and then a set containing some of those $z$'es with $x$ to forms a basis. This would make the proof larger and confusing when looking at the sub-numbers when that basis should contain $n$ elements, for example the basis $\{x,z_2,z_7,\dots, z_m\}$. In order to fix this, I simply said "there exists $x_2,\dots, x_n\in V$ ..." where $x_1$ (probably) could be $z_2$ in this case and so on. This would make the reader easier to follow. What do you think? I hope you understand my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems correct, but I don't think I understand exactly what you think is wrong with it (I don't get what you mean when you talk about the $z$'s), but anyway, I will try to clear up your doubts:
If $V$ is a vector space, then any set of linearly independent vectors that span $V$ is called a basis. So there are many basis for a particular vector space $V$; the theorem you mention asserts that every set of linearly independent vectors can be completed to a basis (by possibly adding vectors), so the use you make of it is totally correct.